# html entity decode fail with the new lines in textareas

Tags: javascript, html

when I get a text from a textarea in html like this

```
&#119;&#97;&#115;&#101;&
;#101;&#109;
```

the correct decode is `waseem`

notice the newline , when I decode it I get

```
wase&;#101;m
```

the newline make errors here , Can I fix it ? I use javascript in the decoding process .

I use this function in decoding

```
function html_entity_decode(str) {  
 var  ta=document.createElement("textarea");

 ta.innerHTML=str.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");

 return ta.value;       
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `;` at the begin of the second line?

Comment: How are you aquiring the text from a textarea that contains these escapes in the first place.

Comment: @Anthony  var submitted_text = $("#text").val();

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it through the following regex - Replace

```
&[\s\r\n]+;(?=#\d+;)
```

with

```
&
```

globally. Your HTML entity format is simply broken. Apart from the fact that HTML entities cannot contain whitespace and newlines, they cannot contain semi-colons in the middle.

Comment: The question is why is this even necessary?

Comment: I have no idea. I just saw the broken input.

Answer (score 0):

Your input text may not be right and it is working as intended. Garbage-In-Garbage-Out.

I suspect the &\n; should be something else. But if not:

```
str.replace(/&\s*;/g, "");
```